# bnlearn: predicting NULL target variable

Tags: r, null, predict

I'm using the bnlearn package in R and the tree.bayes function to classify sales data into a WIN or LOSE category. I have it working almost perfectly except when it has to "predict" sales which have a NULL category (ie. their outcome is neither win or lose yet). The values of the target variable are WIN or LOSE, and I want it to predict when the target variable in the test data is NULL or unknown or Open??
It works if i randomly assign WIN or LOSE to the NULL values but this isn't ideal.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Please do post a small example dataset and your expected result as your description is a bit tricky to follow